# Outputting a list to a tsv file in python

Tags: python, list, csv

This seems simple, but I couldn't find an answer. How do I go about outputting a flat list to a tsv file in python?

Comment: what have you tried.. have you used the csv module? or even better look at pandas to_csv class..https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html...https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Using the csv module writer, you can set a `delimiter` flag, which you will want to set to `\t`

Comment: I tried that. Every item in the list is a string, and if i set the deliminter flag to \t it splits every character in every item for the list.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Python's CSV library with a `\t` delimiter as follows:

```
import csv        

data = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']    

with open('output.tsv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    tsv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
    tsv_output.writerow(data)
```

Giving you `output.tsv` containing one row as:

```
text1   text2   text3   text4
```

If you are using Python 2.x, use:

```
with open('output.tsv', 'wb') as f_output:
```